# Oracle query to return each half hour values

Tags: sql, oracle

While I am running this query I get the data showing the time for which i have records. I also wanted to see zeros for the time I don't have data..

```
SELECT x.TIMESLOT AS "FROM", SUM(x.VALUE) AS x.VALUE
FROM 
(SELECT TO_CHAR (dd.create_dt, 'HH24') || DECODE (SIGN (TO_CHAR (dd.create_dt, 'MI') - 30),-1, '01','31') AS TIMESLOT, COUNT(*) AS VALUE FROM deposits LEFT JOIN d_user u ON u.ID = dd.USER_ID WHERE dd.create_dt BETWEEN :p_from_dt AND :p_to_dt  AND dd.ACTIVE_IND = 'Y' GROUP BY TO_CHAR (dd.create_dt, 'HH24') || DECODE (SIGN (TO_CHAR (dd.create_dt, 'MI') - 30),-1, '01','31') 
UNION ALL 
SELECT TO_CHAR (wd.create_dt, 'HH24') || DECODE (SIGN (TO_CHAR (wd.create_dt, 'MI') - 30), -1, '01', '31') AS TIMESLOT, COUNT(*) AS VALUE
FROM wages wd 
WHERE wd.create_dt BETWEEN :p_from_dt AND :p_to_dt 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR (wd.create_dt, 'HH24') || DECODE (SIGN (TO_CHAR (wd.create_dt, 'MI') - 30), -1, '01','31')) x
GROUP BY x.TIMESLOT        
ORDER BY x.TIMESLOT
```

**OUTPUT**

**FROM                            VALUE**

0731                          9
1101                          7
1331                          8
1401                          9
1431                          3
1631                          1

I am trying to get out put as fallows

**OUTPUT**

**FROM                          VALUE**

0601                             0
0631                             0
0701                             0
0731                             9
0801                             0
0831                             0
0901                             0
0931                             0
1001                             0
1031                             0
1101                             7
1131                             0
1201                             0
1231                             0
1301                             0
1331                             8
1401                             9
1431                             3
1501                             0
1531                             0
1601                             0
1631                             1
1701                             0
1731                             0
1801                             0
1831                             0
1901                             0
1931                             0
2001                             0
2031                             0
2101                             0
2131                             0
2201                             0

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a list of all the half hour intervals using the query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE( '0601', 'HH24MI' ) + (LEVEL - 1)/48, 'HH24MI' ) AS timeslot
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY
       LEVEL <= 33;
```

You can then add it in to your query with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`; something like this:

```
WITH half_hours AS (
  SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE( '0601', 'HH24MI' ) + (LEVEL - 1)/48, 'HH24MI' ) AS timeslot
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY
         LEVEL <= 33
), data AS (
  <your_query>
)
SELECT h.timeslot,
       COALESCE( d.value, 0 ) AS value
FROM   half_hours h
       LEFT OUTER JOIN data d
       ON h.timeslot = d.timeslot;
```

Comment: Thank You this exactly what I needed. Works Perfectly in my case.

Comment: If this did solve your question then you can mark the answer as accepted to indicate the question is closed.